# Tomcat 6.0 doesn't set Cookies in webkit based browsers on localhost

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies, webkit, tomcat6

I'm working on a website that runs on Tomcat 6.0 at localhost:8080. Interestingly enough, Tomcat seems to only be able to set cookies on Firefox. Opera and WebKit based browsers (Chrome, WinSafari) seem to fail. Is this a known issue and is there a solution?

Comment: Did you check whether cookies are enabled in Chrome/Safari? I know its a bit silly to ask this, but Chrome/Safari have an explicit (easy to change than others) option to block cookies...

Comment: yep, cookies are definitely enabled in both browsers as I regularly use them for gmail and various other sites requiring their use. In fact, Chrome is my main browser and it's quite the pain to not be able to use webkit's js debug tools :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was we were using a blank string as our cookie domain value. This works in Firefox. I had tried changing the base to locahost and 127.0.0.1 but that hadn't worked previously. There are two reasons for this: the cookies spec requires domains to have 2 or 3 dots in them (hence localhost shouldn't technically work, even though it's aliased). Also, the app host base was localhost:8080, and it's been changed to 127.0.0.1:8080. This satisfies the same domain condition.